# What is the limitation for k-fold cross validation in terms of samples per class?

Tags: cross-validation

I would like to know if it make sense to apply k-fold cross validation (e.g., k = 5 or 10), when the number of samples per class is limited, for example 4 samples for each class.

Would it be better to apply Leave-One-Out (LOO) in such a scenario? If yes, is it still approriate for classification sceanarios with thousands of classes, due to the high variance caused by LOO?

Comment: Is the low-sample "class" that you mention the target of your analysis (i.e., the dependent variable)?

Comment: The data sets I have are mostly ballanced, which means that for each class there is the same number of samples...